# Renaming files in a UNIX directory - shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I have been trying to write a script that will take the current working directory, scan every file and check if it is a .txt file. Then take every file (that's a text file), and check to see if it contains an underscore anywhere in its name and if it does to change the underscore to a hyphen.

I know that this is a tall order, but here is the rough code I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=1
while((count <= $#))
       do
          case $count in
               "*.txt") sed 's/_/-' $count
          esac
          ((count++))
done
```

What I was thinking is that this would take the files in the current working directory as the arguments and check every file(represented by $count or the file at "count"). Then for every file, it would check if it ended in .txt and if it did it would change every underscore to a hyphen using sed. I think one of the main problems I am having is that the script is not reading the files from the current working directory. I tried included the directory after the command to run the script, but I think it took each line instead of each file (since there are 4 or so files on every line).

Anyway, any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, I'm sorry that my code is so bad, I am very new to UNIX.

Comment: One problem is that `$count` is the value of the variable `count`, which is some integer. If you want to iterate over the positional parameters, you'd write: `for file in "$@"; do ...` or the shorthand `for file; do ...`

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Answer (score 2):

```
for fname in ./*_*.txt; do
  new_fname=$(printf '%s' "$fname" | sed 's,_,-,')
  mv "$fname" "$new_fname"
done
```

Comment: If the shell is bash, one can write: `new_fname=${fname//_/-}`

Answer (score 1):

why not:

```
rename 's/_/-/' *.txt
```

Comment: `rename: command not found`. The question is about Unix, not a particular Linux distribution. But given that Perl is installed almost everywhere, it's a nice and flexible solution.

Comment: @RolandIllig: I know `rename` is not everywhere, but from shebang I assumed it's executed on some modern unix-like system.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ls *.txt | while read -r file; do echo $file | 
  grep > /dev/null _ && mv $file $(echo $file | tr _ -); done
```

(untested)

Comment: This will fail on files containing spaces in filename. You may even loose some data if yo do wrong `mv`.

Comment: Yes, it will fail on files containing spaces.  People who put spaces in their file names deserve to lose all their data. :)

Comment: I kind of agree... :-) However we are here to learn of each other that is why I added this comment. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your input guys! All in all, I think the solution I found was the most appropriate for my skill level was:

```
ls *.txt | while read -r file; do echo file |
   mv $file $(echo $file | sed 's,_,-,');
done
```

This got what I needed done, and for my purposes I am not too worried about the spaces. But thanks for all your wonderful suggestions, you are all very intelligent!